# How apply the filter function in data Frame for '?' character

Tags: python, dataframe, filter

How filter the character like "?" in data frame filter function
Ex: `df_new = df[df.filter( regex='?',axis=1)]`
This is giving all the elements in the Data Frame(df)

Comment: `regex='.*\?.*'` will match all strings containing '?'

Comment: Also have you tried: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical case where the character you want to find has already a use in regex as an operator and must be 'escaped' (i.e. you have to make it explicit that you want the alphanumeric character and not the operator).

In most langages, you just have to add an backslash (`'\'`) in front of the symbol. Hence, if you're looking for `'?'`, you should do:

```
df_new = df[df.filter(regex='\?',axis=1)]
```